# Problems trying to query an element with a numeric pattern in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to retrieve the users from a collection with the starting telephone number pattern 622.

I tried to do it with a $regexp expression but I think is focused on string and the telephone number is numeric.

```
db.alumnes.find({telefon: /^622/})
```

This doesn't retrieve anything, however, the collection has elements with that starting pattern.

Can someone help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned rightly regex apply to strings hence the above query will not work . However , using mathematical operations we can get the first three digits of a number and then compare that to 622 to get all telephone numbers . 
Below mongodb query uses the aggregation framework to get the required results  ( it might not work for negative number or less than 4 digit numbers) .

```
* Get total digits in the number using log base 10 
* Subtract 3 
* Raise the result to power of 10 
* Perform floor division to get the first 3 digits of the number  
* Finally compare the 3 digits obtained with 622.

db.alumnes.aggregate([{"$project":{"_id":1,"telefon":1, bits:{"$floor":{"$divide":["$telefon",{"$pow":[10,{"$add":[{$ceil:{"$log10":"$telefon"}},-3]}]}]}}}},{"$match":{"bits":622}}])
```